# Add a button for random playback of tracks in the player

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a small player to my site to listen to music. I found a beautiful example that I liked and want to change and finish it a little.

Specifically, I want to add a button here to randomly play tracks.

To start, I add this button to the html:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-random">
   <i class="fas fa-random"></i>
</button>
```

Next, I add a check to the next track switching function, if the random button has an active class, then the tracks will play randomly:

```
else if (to == 'next') {
        stop();
        if (document.getElementById("btn-random").classList.contains("active")) {
          let songs = document.getElementById("sourceUrl").length - 1;
          let randomSong = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs) + 1;
        } else {
          currentSong = (++currentSong)%playlist.length;
        }
        playpause();
    }
```

Next, it remains to make sure that when you click on the random button, the active class turns on and off. To do this, I make a onclick function for this button and implement it:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-random" onclick="random()">
   <i class="fas fa-random"></i>
</button>

//

var randomTrack = false;

function random() {
  if (randomTrack) {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.add("active");
        randomTrack = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.remove("active");
        randomTrack = true;
    }
}
```

But in the end, when the random button has an active class and I try to switch the song, instead of a random track, the current track plays in a circle.

What could be the problem?

```js
var song = new Audio;
var isStopped = true;
var currentSong = 0;
var playlist = [];
var playlistVisible = false;
var randomTrack = false;

function skip(to) {
    if (to == 'prev') {
        stop();
        currentSong = (--currentSong)%playlist.length;
        if (currentSong < 0) {
            currentSong += playlist.length;
        }
        playpause();
    }
    else if (to == 'next') {
        stop();
        if (document.getElementById("btn-random").classList.contains("active")) {
          let songs = document.getElementById("sourceUrl").length - 1;
              let randomSong = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs) + 1;
        } else {
          currentSong = (++currentSong)%playlist.length;
        }
        playpause();
    }
}

function playpause() {
  if (!song.paused) {
        song.pause();
        document.getElementById("glow").classList.add("disable-animation");
    }
  else if (playlist.length == 0){
    togglePlaylist();
  }
    else {
      if (isStopped) {
            song.src = playlist[currentSong];
        }
        song.play();
        songFile = playlist[currentSong].split("/");
        songName = document.getElementById("songName");
        songName.innerHTML = songFile[songFile.length - 1].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
        document.getElementById("glow").classList.remove("disable-animation");
        isStopped = false;
    }
}

function random() {
  if (randomTrack) {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.add("active");
        randomTrack = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn-random').classList.remove("active");
        randomTrack = true;
    }
}

function stop() {
    song.pause();
    document.getElementById("glow").classList.add("disable-animation");
    song.currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("seek").value = 0;
    isStopped = true;
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = "playing track..";
}

function setPos(pos) {
    song.currentTime = pos;
}

function mute() {
    if (song.muted) {
        song.muted = false;
        document.getElementById('mute').className = "fa fa-volume-up";
    }
    else {
        song.muted = true;
        document.getElementById('mute').className = "fa fa-volume-off";
    }
}

function setVolume(volume) {
    song.volume = volume;
}

function togglePlaylist() {
    if (playlistVisible) {
        document.getElementById('playlist').className = "hide";
        document.getElementById('player').className = "";
        playlistVisible = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('player').className = "hide";
        document.getElementById('playlist').className = "";
        playlistVisible = true;
    }
}

function addList() {
    sourceUrl = document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value;
    sourceUrl.split(",").forEach((file) => {
        fileUrl = file.trim();
        if (fileUrl != "" && playlist.indexOf(fileUrl) == -1) {
            parent = document.getElementById('list');
            listItem = document.createElement('div');
            listItem.setAttribute('class','list-item');

            wrapper = document.createElement('div');
            wrapper.setAttribute('class','wrap-text');

            span = document.createElement('span');
      songFile = fileUrl.split("/");
            span.innerHTML = songFile[songFile.length - 1].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');

            wrapper.appendChild(span);
            listItem.appendChild(wrapper);

            btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.setAttribute('onclick','removeList(this)');
            btn.innerHTML = '&times;';

            listItem.appendChild(btn);
            parent.appendChild(listItem);
            playlist.push(fileUrl);
        }
    });
  document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value = '';
}

function removeList(item) {
    index = playlist.indexOf(item.parentElement.firstChild.innerText);
    if (index != -1){
        playlist.splice(index,1);
        item.parentElement.remove();
    }
}

song.addEventListener('error', function(){
    stop();
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = "error loading audio";
});

song.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    curtime = parseInt(song.currentTime,10);
    document.getElementById('seek').max = song.duration;
    document.getElementById('seek').value = curtime;
});

song.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    song.pause();
    song.currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('seek').value = 0;
    if ((currentSong + 1) >= playlist.length) {
        currentSong = 0;    
    }
    else {
        currentSong++;
    }
    stop();
    song.src = playlist[currentSong];
    playpause();
});

var input = document.getElementById("sourceUrl");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addList();
    }
});


// This area of code is only for preview purposes only

document.getElementById('sourceUrl').value = ["https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-summer.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-anewbeginning.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-littleidea.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-cute.mp3",
"https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-memories.mp3"];
addList();
document.getElementById("glow").classList.remove("disable-animation");

// Code for preview ends here
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  background: #000000;
}
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.glow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, #262626);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.glow::before,
.glow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #ebc6df,
    #ebc6c9,
    #e1c6eb,
    #c6c9eb,
    #c6e8eb,
    #e373fb,
    #f787e6,
    #cb87f7,
    #87a9f7,
    #87f7ee
  );
  background-size: 400%;
  max-width: calc(300px + 4px);
  max-height: calc(300px + 4px);
  width: calc(300px + 4px);
  height: calc(300px + 4px);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.disable-animation::before,
.disable-animation::after {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.glow::after {
  filter: blur(28px);
}
#player,
#playlist {
  width: 243px;
  height: 212px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#songName {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.playlist-btn {
  width: 243px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
#list {
  height: 118px;
  max-height: 118px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.list-item {
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.list-container button {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.add-list {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.wrap-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 190px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sourceUrl {
  background: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #1f1f1f;
  border-radius: 47px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 192px;
}
#sourceUrl:active,
#sourceUrl:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0088ff;
}
.text {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
button {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000, #262626);
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0px #ffffff61;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px 0px #ffffff61;
}

#seek,
#volume {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #232323;
  outline: none;
}
#seek::-webkit-slider-thumb,
#volume::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#seek {
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  max-width: 5px;
  max-height: 5px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #333;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #5c6670;
}

.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #232323;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="glow" class="glow disable-animation">
    <div id="player">
      <span class="text">iu player</span>
      <br>
      <span id="songName" class="text">playing track..</span>
      <br>
      <div class="playback_controls">
        <button onclick="skip('prev')">
          <i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="playpause()">
          <i class="fa fa-play"></i><i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="stop()">
          <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
        </button>
        <button onclick="skip('next')">
          <i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="seekbar">
        <input type="range" oninput="setPos(this.value)" id="seek" value="0" max="">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="volume_controls">
        <button onclick="mute()">
          <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        </button>
        <input type="range" id="volume" oninput="setVolume(this.value)" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="1">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="playlist" class="hide">
      <span class="text">iu playlist</span>
      <div class="list-container">

        <div id="list" class="scrollbar"></div>

        <div class="add-list">
          <input id="sourceUrl" type="text" placeholder="enter audio url" />
          <button onclick="addList()">+</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="playlist-btn">
      <button id="btn-random" onclick="random()">
        <i class="fas fa-random"></i>
      </button>
      <button onclick="togglePlaylist()">
        <i id="playlist-btn" class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of status code 409 and stepped through the code in the debugger to find what might be causing the conflict?

Comment: @Yogi I tried to run it again and I no longer have this error, it's just that when I switch to the next track, the current one is turned on again. I can't find what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never reading your `randomSong` variable.

Just set `currentSong` to `Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)` in that case:

```js
if (
    document.getElementById("btn-random").classList.contains("active")
) {
    currentSong = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
} else {
    currentSong = ++currentSong % playlist.length;
}
playpause();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works, but there is one moment, when the track that is the previous one in the list is turned on at random, an error occurs in the console

Comment: it does not affect the work in any way, does not interfere with anything, but maybe it can be somehow removed `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`